# Where Can I get windows XP drivers for ASUS X551C?

Tags: windows-xp, drivers, display-driver

I have tried to get windows xp drivers for my Asus X551C laptop. I couldnt get right driver for display to adjust its brightness. I tried to install audio , chipset and networking from some where in net. But I couldnt find one for the display. 
Please help me to get drivers for my laptop.

Answer (score 2):

```
Version V1.0.0031

Description ATKACPI driver and hotkey-related utilities
File Size   12.62 MBytesupdate 2013/12/12
Download from   Global
```

[Link](http://dlcdnet.asus.com/pub/ASUS/nb/Apps_for_Win8/ATKPackage/ATKPackage_Win7_64_VER100031.zip)

There are only 64bit drivers available, so if you've installed 32bit its probable that it will be impossible to use those functions. If you are using 64bit then these Win7 drivers may function on XP if you're lucky.

Really that PC postdates XP by a long shot and Asus wouldn't have considered XP compatibility. As XP is unpatched now it should be avoided unless you REALLY need it.

Comment: thanks for your supportive answer. really i prefer xp instead of latest one. Because simple and good to run, i dont need much trendy UI, just simple UI with necessary functions to run  on a decent machine. i feel xp is fine to go. i have tried upto 10 nd all other linux series too. but i am comfortable with XP

Comment: @Kvvaradha It's less to do with how simple or trendy it looks, and more to do with the fact Microsoft are no longer releasing security patches. As such, should a serious vulnerability be found and exploited, there's no recourse for it and you'll be using a potentially risky machine, from a security standpoint.

Comment: @Kvvaradha the fact that you are "comfortable" with XP is irrelevant if you care about the security of your personal details or credit card details. XP will have no security fixes and many new browser versions are either unsupported or will not work on XP. You are leaving yourself wide open to massive security problems.